# I get it vs I got it

Tags: word-choice, idioms, tenses, speech

What would you say to show you’ve understood?

1. I get it.
2. I got it.

I think both are interchangeable; can any native speaker help me out?

Comment: Either one. They mean the same in this context.

Comment: #1 to claim understanding; #2 to claim the bill at a restaurant. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's almost the same, no difference.

Grammatically, **I get it** is Present simple, while **I got it** is Past Simple.

Usually, A British English speaker would say "I've got it". (Thanks @Kate Bunting)

Comment: A British English speaker would say "I've got it".

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that English use more Present Perfect, tbh I use more **I got it**. But I've got it is wrong, shouldn't It be I've gotten it?

Comment: @Matteo Even North Americans would say “I’ve got it now” rather than ”I’ve gotten it now”.

Comment: Ok, Is that grammatically right?

Comment: @tchrist: The fact that even AmE uses present perfect when explicitly coupled to ***now*** suggests that dropping the ***'ve*** is just a "lazy / vernacular" device that blurs a potential fine distinction always available to the careful BrE speaker (How recently did I get it? Did it matter that I got it *then*, or *now?*).

Comment: Trending phrase seems to be "I get that, but . . . [and go right on with the argument]